# Deleting data by clicking DELETE button which is in table heading

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am fetching 10 records in table, now i have one table column heading named DELETE, below which there are checkboxes now i want to delete checked records on single click of that DELETE button.Pls tell how to do it in php codeigniter

```
<table>
     <tr>
            <td>Id</td>  
            <td>Name</td>  
            <td>Car</td>  
            <td>Address</td>  
            <td>Phone Number</td> 
            <td><a href="<?php echo site_url('User1/delete/'); ?>">Delete</td>          
            <td>Action </td>    
    </tr>

     <?php foreach($posts as $a){  ?>
     <tr>
            <td><?php echo $a->id;?></td>  
            <td><?php echo $a->name;?></td>  
            <td><?php echo $a->car;?></td>  
            <td><?php echo $a->address;?></td>  
            <td><?php echo $a->cell_number;?></td>  
            <td>
            <input type="checkbox" name="id" value="$a->id"><br>
            </td>
      </tr>    
     <?php }?>  
   </table>
```

Controller Code

```
function delete($id){
    $result = $this->User_model->deletebyid($id);
    if($result==true)
    return true;
}
```

Model Code

```
function deletebyid($id){
    $this->db->where('id', $id);
    $this->db->delete('user_table');
    if ($this->db->affected_rows() > 0) {
      return true;
    }else {
      return false;
    }
}
```

Getting this error

```
A Database Error Occurred

Error Number: 1054

Unknown column 'Array' in 'where clause'

DELETE FROM `user_table` WHERE `id` = `Array`

Filename: C:/xampp/htdocs/codeigniter/system/database/DB_driver.php

Line Number: 691
```

Comment: Where is your TRIED Code?

Comment: As I see, This can be acheived in 2 ways. 1) jquery : pass all id's of checked checkbox 2) put `<table>` inside `<form>`

Comment: `delete($id)` delete single row. But, you are having array values to it.

Comment: the "href" with the delete function should be written in the table's body inside the foreach, not in the table header.

Comment: how will that DELETE button will get all that checked ids pls elaborate and thanks@NanaPartykar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<form method='post' action='<?php echo site_url('User1/delete/'); ?>' >
<table>
     <tr>
            <td>Id</td>  
            <td>Name</td>  
            <td>Car</td>  
            <td>Address</td>  
            <td>Phone Number</td> 
            <td><input type="submit" name="delete" value="Delete" /></td>          
            <td>Action </td>    
    </tr>

     <?php foreach($posts as $a){  ?>
     <tr>
            <td><?php echo $a->id;?></td>  
            <td><?php echo $a->name;?></td>  
            <td><?php echo $a->car;?></td>  
            <td><?php echo $a->address;?></td>  
            <td><?php echo $a->cell_number;?></td>  
            <td>
            <input type="checkbox" name="r_id[]" value="<?php echo $a->id; ?>"><br>
            </td>
      </tr>    
     <?php }?>  
   </table>  
</form>
```

Controller:

```
function delete($id){
echo "<pre>";print_r($_POST['r_id']);exit; // you will get all selected check box values. (which are the record ids. You just send this ids to model and delete them using sql IN operator [ex: id IN ('') ].
...
...
...
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Make this change in your code to work

```
<input type="checkbox" name="record_ids[]" value="$a->id">
```

And in your controller access them like

**Controller**

```
function delete(){
   $record_ids = $this->input->post('record_ids');

   $result = $this->User_model->deletebyid($record_ids);
   if($result==true)
      return true;    
}
```

**Model**

**---- Update to handle single delete ----**

```
function deletebyid($ids){
   if(is_array($ids))
      $this->db->where_in('id', $ids);
   else
      $this->db->where('id',$ids);
   $this->db->delete('user_table');
   if ($this->db->affected_rows() > 0) {
     return true;
   }
   else
     return false;
 }
```

Comment: Actually i have one function in model for deleting one record wrt $id. Should i make one more function to delete more than one checked records.

Comment: now one more error,missing argument user1::delete2(), i think function is not getting that checked $ids

Comment: how could i get that checked values using jquery.

Comment: Can you just `print_r($this->input->post('record_ids'));` in your controller and check what you are getting

Comment: Good...If anything helped from answer you can mark it as an answer

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this. You put the record ID in the link
Model:

```
function delete_row() //model named displaym
{
    $this->db->where('id', $this->uri->segment(3)); //this will be the table row ID
    $this->db->delete('table');//table name
}
```

Controller

```
public function delete()
{
    $this->is_logged_in();
    $this->displaym->delete_row();
    redirect("page");
}
```

When you link to delete controller

```
anchor("updates/delete/" . $row->id, //send table row ID to the model as the 3rd segement
```